# AJENTI + CLOUDFLARE + NGINX bind() failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)

Tags: nginx, server, dns, cloudflare

I recently started to use Cloudflare.

If the site use proxied dns ajenti throws nginx error:

> nginx: [emerg] bind() to ip_here:80 failed (99: Cannot assign
> requested address)

If I disable proxy and I use DNS ONLY MODE it works fine.

I want to keep proxied Cloudflare DNS because of the free SSL cert.

**How can I make Cloudflare and Ajenti work together?**

Comment: Have you implemented SSL on Nginx ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure SSL Settings in Cloudflare for that based on the configuration you already have.

1. If you have an SSL and is running on 443 port on NGINX then go to SSL/TLS tab in Cloudflare and make sure `Full` option is selected under mode.
2. If you have your application running on 80 port in NGINX then you should validate that under SSL/TLS tab, `Flexible` option is selected.

Once this is setup then you can go with proxied Cloudflare DNS. It should work fine.